# how can I render Smoke&fire in Cycles 2.79?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

I`m attaching 2 screenshots to illustrate my problem, I made a generic explosion simulation which looks fine in Material\Object mode, and the next screenshot demonstrates what I actually get when trying to render it.
Tried to bake it, changed to CPU, nothing works. Would be glad to know how to solve it[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq0aj.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information - a screenshot of your material nodes for your smoke domain would be really helpful.

Comment: I attached it to my question, but I didn`t do anything with them, all by deafault. I mean I only tweaked Particles and Physics tabs just a little bit and that`s it

Comment: Thanks. The Quick Smoke material is smoke only -  but the final Add node includes a spare socket for ‘flame’ if you need it. See Bigfoot Blondie’s answer for a setup to include flame.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly. Your nodes:
[image]

This setup is by no means perfect but it should work. Attach it to your smoke simulation domain.

If that doesn't work, try placing down a single circle, filled. Go to:

Objects --> Quick Effects --> Quick Smoke.

Play animation...

If you render and it works, then there is something wrong with your nodes/object. I recommend trying to recreate your previous attempt.
As annoying as it may seem, you should have a better idea on how to recreate it and will replicate it faster.

If it doesn't work there may be something you have changed in your render settings. Try doing the Quick Smoke method on a new document and see if it works. I still have much learn about blender myself so I can't help you there, sorry.
There shouldn't be any issues with GPU rendering in 2.79.

Good luck, Hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: additional nodes didn`t change anything. I guess I`ll have to recreate it from scratch. In a new project default Quick Smoke does render... Hm just created another new project and it doesn`t render anymore. Such a sorcery

Comment: Ahh, yes. I don't use smoke/fire simulations much so I don't have to deal with its nonsense. But with everything I have ever done, If it doesn't work and you hit a roadblock for a while, just start again. This is particularly true with simulations and particles as so many things can go wrong. Again, Goodluck with your projects - BFB